Does this image fit a strophoid curve?
$1.$ Does the curve pictured here fit a strophoid curve?  I used a plot of $r = sin(\phi\theta)$ because one of the strophoid forms below.

I see from posts this looks similar to a "right strophoid".  Here is the formula I used and what appears a curve fit.  Also note, the right strophoid can be created using a polar plot with $sin(theta)$ as I described in original post.  Here is Cartesian:
$y^2 = \frac {a-x}{a+x} (b-x)^2$ for parameters I use $a=2.5, b=1.8$.
Image with above Strophoid equation:

$3.$ Backup Pictures

Original to match curve:


The first one looks like $x^3+y^3=3axy$

That looks really close but it appears height is too long even when changing the constant a. Did you try to superimpose yours? Also what function is that some conic?

Folks, I'm trying to use Blue and Gwen's formula in the post below.  It's requiring many iterations of the formula for a match.  Does anyone know of software that will let me modify the curve and overlay a layer of image on it with opacity at the same time?  I'm using Gimp and Grapher right now to do this and it's slow

@Nick: "Does anyone know of software that will let me modify the curve and overlay a layer of image on it with opacity at the same time?" Desmos allows this. Follow the link to the graph in Gwen's answer. Use the "+" in the upper-left to add an image; then you can adjust position, orientation, opacity, etc.

Does this suffice
$$(y-b)^2=(x+b)^2\frac{a^2-x}{a^2+x}$$
You can regulate it's roundness and height, I guess

Thanks I’ll try so,e coefficients to see if it matches. Have you found the ones that match?

No I don't have the original picture that you used @Nick

This is a nice little family of curves. I might tidy-up the equation a bit by writing $$y^2;=;\frac{a-x}{a+x},(b-x)^2$$ Removing the $b$ on the left-hand side keeps the curve symmetric in the $x$-axis. Replacing $a^2$ with $a$ makes for dimensional consistency, so that $a$ and $b$ represent (signed) lengths, like $x$ and $y$. The $x$-intercepts are $a$ and $b$ (the cross-point), and there's a vertical asymptote at $x=-a$. For $|b|<|a|$, the curve is a loop; when $b=0$, this is specifically a right strophoid.

Than youuu soo much @Blue I totally forgot it's name

@Blue I see right strophoid $\alpha = \pi/2$ in
$r=a\frac{\sin(2\theta-\alpha)}{\sin(\theta-\alpha)}$, the result is the similar formula I post in OP, the division by $sin$ limits the number of "petals" in the polar plot.  I tried formula you post above $a=1, b=2$ and get images close to the elongated ones Yves posts below.  The can also be created using the prior formula I add here with $sin(a\theta)$ changing value of $a$.  I think this may be the formula for the Ankh!

So it appears Egyptians may have known formula to the "right strophoid" either in Cartesian (quadratic) or Polar form (with trigonometry sin/cos) to create the Ankh.

I think the only question I have is converting the polar (with sin) to cartesian and seeing where $\phi$ appears, as right strophoid polar using sin with $\phi$ is a match as well as the cartesian.
